# Can I remove console_bridge dependency in class_loader when installing from source?

Tags: ros, build-from-source, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the indigo release "robot" set of packages on armhf from source.

For the class_loader package, the changelog states:

0.2.0 (2013-03-13)

- use find_package for Poco/dl instead to make it work on other platforms
- update Poco cmake file to include libdl on non-windows systems
- No longer CATKIN_DEPEND on console_bridge

However the packages CMakeLists.txt still contains (on line 9)

**find package(console_bridge REQUIRED)**

Am I safe in removing the requirement?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189395/can-i-remove-console_bridge-dependency-in-class_loader-when-installing-from-source?/) by [kurt.christofferson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4082/kurt.christofferson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a bad idea. Even if class_loader isn't exporting the dependency on console_bridge, it's probably still depending on it internally.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0